# Need to evaluate the loop gain of a corrector stage

Tags: loop-gain

I would want to simulate the loop gain of a corrector stage. I have no idea to add the static point at the output (Vout) of the opamp (3.6039875V).
What is the method to simulate the loop gain of this corrector?

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Solution 1: Use an IDEAL opamp model without any offset.
Solution 2: Use a resistor across the feedback capacitor (as large as possible with respect to offset voltages)